# spark 1.6.0 compilation failed on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-spark, ubuntu-15.10

I was trying to install spark sbt assembly on my laptop on ubuntu 15.10 and after the compilation I got a message the compilation failed. This is the second time I am doing that, it worked fine for the first time but I had to reinstall the system and now I'm trying to do it again but it's not working this time.

The last part of the output in the terminal is full of lines starting with [error]. Close to the end it says:

```
[error] uncaught exception during compilation: java.io.IOException
[error] File name too long
```

When I tried to run

```
bin/spark-shell
```

I got message 'bin/spark-shell: line 57: /usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory'

Before installing in stand alone mode I tried to install spark on top of hadoop 2.7.1 which I installed before but it did not work and running examples failed.

Can anybody suggest what should I look for a problem?

Comment: sbt or maven,which one did you use? I suggest maven.

Comment: I used sbt, not maven.

Comment: It turned out the problem was the disk encryption which causes errors during attempts of spark installation... If you encrypt 'home', you won't be able to install spark.